# Javascript - Update to existing function onClick call

Tags: javascript, onclick, infowindow

This is inside an infowindow.

ISSUE:
When onClick is clicked, I want to be able change the onClick variable to reflect new value.

So I have an example button setup below:

```
//Loop through database and createMarker below
function createMarker(date) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map
    });
    setMarkers.push(marker); 
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    content = "<input type='button' value='Update' id='gPlan' onClick='updateMarker(\""+date+"\");'>";
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
   });
}


function updateMarker(date) {
var newdate = document.getElementById('datetimepicker').value;
//change the onClick button that was clicked, update "date" to "newdate" value 
//Next onClick will reflect on the "newdate" instead of the original "date"

}
```

How do you go about achieving this? Do I have to reset(delete and replace old) marker infowindow? Is there an easier way?

Comment: We need to see more code, including the loop. Also, you should add a Google Maps tag.

Comment: I don't think loop is the issue here, since I can save, delete and update just fine to the database... just not the onClick. Maybe I need to read more on how exactly to pass and update values inside the addListener... Not sure where to begin tho

Comment: You have the same id in each InfoWindow if that's in your loop. One id per page.